# How to train a machine learning model with multiple attributes and one target value?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, features, binary-classification

I'm working on a machine learning problem where I need to guess which customers will churn and which of them will continue to be customers.

I have $X_0, X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5$ and $X_6$ attributes representing if they have credit cards, if they are active customers, if they have money in their accounts, etc. So, according to these multiple $X$ values and the target value $Y$, which is either $0$ or $1$, I need to develop a model that can do the prediction.

I have always worked with only one $X$ attribute and one target value $Y$. Right now, I'm confused about how I should work with multiple $X_n$ values.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How does your model work right now? For a neural network, all you have to do is increase the number of input neurons.

Comment: Thank you @S2673, but since I didn't know how to use multiple X values I was doing a research on how to do it. And I haven't tried neural networks.

Comment: So how does your model work right now?

Comment: I don't have a model because I don't get the idea of how to use multiple input attributes and obtain one target attribute. If I can understand what technique I should use theoretically I can build a model.

Comment: You should probably be using a neural network. There are a bunch of places online where you can learn about it. How did your model using one X and one Y work?

Comment: Thank you I'll definitely look into neural networks! @S2673